# i have python 33 but unable to import numpy and matplotlib package

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am unable to import numpy and matplotlib package in python33. I am getting this error. I have tried to install this two packages but unable to import. I am getting the following error:

> > > import numpy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import numpy
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
> > >       import matplotlib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import matplotlib
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: Did you install either numpy or matplotlib?

Comment: I have downloaded numpy tar file but i have extracted it but nuable to understand in which path should I give the installed package file in python.I have pasted the file under the following path: c:/python33/Lib/numpy 1.8.0

Comment: There are links to installers on the NumPy site. Use one of those. The tar you have isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: You might find it easier to install one of the distributions listed on the scipy install page

Answer (score 1):

The numpy and matplotlib installers are available on the official site: http://www.scipy.org/install.html#individual-packages

Use them. Make sure you get the right version. You're on windows, so you want the EXE corresponding to the latest version of the library and the version of Python you're using (3.3).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that first uninstall numpy and matplotlib using `pip uninstall` command then install again using `pip install` from python command line terminal and restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

As numpy and matplotlib will be useful in multiple projects, I would suggest to install them globally. Go to the command line and type the following commands:

```
pip install -g numpy
pip install -g matplotlib
```